# How to override the default encrypted property prefix/suffix?

Tags: jasypt

Jasypt expects encrypted properties to be wrapped with "ENC(...)".
I'm looking for a way to override the default jasypt encrypted property prefix and suffix with a custom ones like "secure[...]".
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pure jasypt library it is required to write your own version of existing `EncryptableProperties` as default one supports only `ENC(` as prefix and `)` as suffix.

```java
public class EncryptableProperties extends Properties {


    private final String prefix;

    private final String suffix;

    private final StringEncryptor encryptor;

    public EncryptableProperties(final Properties defaults, final StringEncryptor encryptor,
                                 final String prefix, final String suffix) {
        super(defaults);
        this.encryptor = encryptor;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public EncryptableProperties(final Properties defaults, final StringEncryptor encryptor){
        this(defaults,encryptor,"ENC(", ")");
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        String value = super.getProperty(key);
        return decode(value);
    }


    private String decode(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return value;
        }

        String decryptedValue = value;
        if (value.startsWith(prefix) && value.endsWith(suffix)) {
            int start = prefix.length();
            int end = value.length() - suffix.length();
            String encryptedValue = value.substring(start, end);

            decryptedValue = encryptor.decrypt(encryptedValue);
        }

        return decryptedValue;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```java
Properties encryptableProperties = new EncryptableProperties(properties,stringEncryptor,"CUSTOM_PREFIX(",")");
```

If you use spring boot integration

You could do this by using following two properties

- `jasypt.encryptor.property.prefix`
- `jasypt.encryptor.property.suffix`

Default one is:

```
jasypt.encryptor.property.prefix=ENC(
jasypt.encryptor.property.suffix=)
```

These properties are available with following library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you pls provide more details about the first (non spring) option? Some code example may be?

Comment: @spoonboy You need to tell us how you plan to use it. You could read the property and just extract the encrypted value between  prefix and suffix and after that just perform decrypt `encryptor.decrypt(...)`, in this case you could define whatever prefix or suffix you want. I believe you use same framework to read properties files ?

Comment: I just use the EncryptableProperties  class instead of the regular Properties.

Comment: @spoonboy It is not possible to change it if you use EncryptableProperties, underlying it uses hardcoded prefix `ENC(` and suffix `)`. You need to create your own ,see my answer is updated.

Comment: Ok, so, basically, the answer is No. The prefix and suffix are hardcoded in the class EncryptableProperties  and furthermore, they are defined as final so you cannot override them in an extending class.  Poor design, IMHO. But, thanks for confirming this anyway.